# ¿Cómo consultar sin repetir registros en mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

```
tabla Imagen
---------------------
idImagen int,
idArticulo varchar(20),
urlImagen varchar(60)


tabla Articulo
---------------------

idArticulo varchar(20), 
descripcion varchar(20), 
modelo      varchar(20),
cantidad    int
```

Los articulos tienen más de una imagen y solo quiero mostrar una.

Lo que hace esta consulta es mostrarme todas las imágenes

```
select DISTINCT(idArticulo), urlImagen from imagen;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta consulta por ejemplo te debería funcionar:

```
select idArticulo, (
    select urlImagen
    from Imagen
    where Imagen.idArticulo = Articulo.idArticulo
    limit 1) as urlImagen
from Articulo;
```

Lo que hace es seleccionar todos los `idArticulo` de la tabla `Articulo`, y para cada uno de ellos busca la primer `urlImagen` de la tabla `Imagen`.

Comment: muchas Gracias , me funciono :) :)